# Quantity increase / decrease pl/sql

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I wrote this procedure that aims to remove items individually based on pno and ono from order details. The removed item will be placed into tables RECORDS and REMOVED_ODETAILS accordingly. Some items purchased by an order more than once, and each item purchase number i.e QTY. My question is How can I decrease the QTY -1 from odetails for items ordered more than once and increase the QTY REMOVED_ODETAILS +1?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ONE_BY_ONE( ORD_NUM IN NUMBER(5), PRO_NUM IN NUMBER(5), QUANTITY NUMBER(5))
AS
CURSOR CUR1
IS
SELECT * FROM ORDERS 
WHERE ONO = ORD_NUM;

CURSOR CUR2
IS
SELECT * FROM ODETAILS
WHERE PNO = PRO_NUM
AND ONO = P_ONO;

VAL1 CUR1%ROWTYPE;
VAL2 CUR2%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

OPEN CUR1;
OPEN CUR2;

LOOP
FETCH CUR1 INTO VAL1;
FETCH CUR2 INTO VAL2;

EXIT WHEN CUR1%NOTFOUND;
EXIT WHEN CUR1%NOTFOUND;


IF VAL1.SHIPPED IS NOT NULL THEN
   IF PRO_NUM = VAL2.PNO AND ORD_NUM = VAL2.ONO THEN
       IF ( VAL2.QTY >  QUANTITY) THEN
    FOR R IN (SELECT ONO, PNO FROM REMOVED_ODETAILS) LOOP
  --CODE NOT CHECK TO INSERT OR UPDATE ON REMOVED_ODETAILS
    IF (R.ONO != ORD_NUM AND R.PNO != PRO_NUM) THEN
    INSERT
      INTO REMOVED_ODETAILS
        (
          ONO,
          PNO,
          QTY
        )
        VALUES
        (
          VAR_CUR2.ONO,
          VAR_CUR2.PNO,
          VAR_CUR2.QTY
        );
        ELSE 
      UPDATE REMOVED_ODETAILS SET QTY = QTY - QUANTITY WHERE ONO = ORD_NUM AND 
                                                            PNO =PRO_NUM;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

      INSERT INTO RECORDS(ID_NUMBER, ONO,CNO,DATE_SEND,CONDITION)
      VALUES(Seq.NEXTVAL, VAL1.ONO,VAL1.CNO,SYSDATE,'SEND BACK');

     ELSIF (VAL2.QTY = QUANTITY ) THEN 
      INSERT INTO RECORDS(ID_NUMBER, ONO,CNO,DATE_SEND,CONDITION)
      VALUES(Seq.NEXTVAL, VAL1.ONO,VAL1.CNO,SYSDATE,'SEND BACK');
     INSERT INTO REMOVED_ODETAILS( ONO, PNO, QTY) 
             VALUES(VAR_CUR2.ONO,VAR_CUR2.PNO, VAR_CUR2.QTY);
      DELETE FROM ODETAILS WHERE ONO = ORD_NUM AND `enter code here`PNO = PRO_NUM;
   END IF;  


       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Item will be send back ');

        DELETE FROM ORDERS 
        WHERE ONO = ORD_NUM and 
        NOT EXISTS (select 1 from ODETAILS where ONO = ORD_NUM );

ELSIF VAL1.SHIPPED IS NULL THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DO NOTHING ');
END IF;

END LOOP;
CLOSE CUR1;
CLOSE CUR2;
END ONE_BY_ONE;
```

CUSTOMERS

```
 create table customers (
  cno      number(5) not null primary key,
  cname    varchar2(30),
  street   varchar2(30),
  zip      number(5) references zipcodes,
  phone    char(12));
```

EMPLOYEES

```
create table employees (
 eno      number(4) not null primary key, 
 ename    varchar2(30),
 zip      number(5) references zipcodes,
 hdate    date);
```

ORDERS

```
create table orders (
  ono      number(5) not null primary key,
  cno      number(5) references customers,
  eno      number(4) references employees,
  received date,
  shipped  date);
```

ODETAILS

```
 create table odetails (
  ono      number(5) not null references orders,
  pno      number(5) not null references parts,
  qty      integer check(qty > 0),
  primary key (ono,pno));
```

RECORDS

```
create table RECORDS
       id_number  number(5) not null primary key,
       ono        number(5) not null,
       cno        number(5) not null,
       date_send  date,
       condition  varchar22(30));
```

REMOVED_ODETAILS

```
create table REMOVED_ODETAILS ( 
      ono      number(5) not null,
      pno      number(5) not null,
      qty      integer check(qty > 0),
      primary key (ono,pno));
```

## BEFORE

ORDERS

```
    ONO         CNO         ENO     RECEIVED DATE   SHIPPED DATE
  ---------- ---------- ----------  -----------     ---------- 
     1112      7000        1004      02-JAN-16      20-DEC-15 
     1113      12345       2002      10-JAN-16      15-DEC-15
     1114      12345       2002      09-JAN-16      14-DEC-15
```

ODETAILS

```
     ONO        PNO         QTY     
  ---------- ---------- ----------  
     1112      12345         3 
     1112      98766         3    
     1113      12345         2
     1114      12345         1
```

## Expected answer (when given specific ono/pno combinations)

RECORDS

```
   ID_NUMBER       ONO      CNO    DATE_SEND     CONDITION 
  ------------   -------  --------  ----------     --------      
    10001         1112     7000    13-JAN-16     SEND BACK 
    10002         1112     7000    13-JAN-16     SEND BACK
    10003         1112     7000    13-JAN-16     SEND BACK 
    10005         1113     12345    14-JAN-16     SEND BACK
    10006         1114     12345    14-JAN-16     SEND BACK
```

REMOVED_ODETAILS

```
     ONO        PNO        QTY
   -------     ------     ------
     1112      12345        2
     1112      98766        1
     1113      12345        1
     1114      12345        1
```

ODETAILS

```
     ONO        PNO         QTY
  ---------- ---------- ----------
    1112       12345          1
    1112       98766          2 
    1113       12345          1
```

ORDERS

```
     ONO        CNO       ENO      RECEIVED DATE   SHIPPED DATE
  ---------- ---------- ----------  -----------  ---------- 
    1112       7000        1004      02-JAN-16     20-DEC-15 
    1113       12345       2002      10-JAN-16     15-DEC-15
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide create table and insert statements, so that we can replicate your tables and test things for ourselves. It would also help if you provided the expected output of what you want to see after the procedure has been run.

Comment: I hope I explained it enough !

Comment: Unfortunately, the extra information you've provided is not enough to allow us to just run your code. That's why I asked for create table scripts (including constraint definitions, such as primary and foreign keys) and insert statements. Imagine you aren't the person who asked this question, but someone without access to the database who wants to help. What information do you think you'd need in order to be able to try and help? The best questions come with a complete test case that other people can take and run for themselves, allowing them to play around with the code until it's working.

Comment: How can I pass you my table script? Can we do it through chat if thats ok?

Comment: Just edit your question and add the information in there. It's okay if you use a cut-down version of your tables/data, so long as they contain enough info for us to be able to run your code.

Comment: The primary Key of the RECORDS table is a sequence so I forgot to include it

Comment: Do you think if I can put a condition after IF PRO_NUM = VAL2.PNO AND ORD_NUM = VAL2.ONO THEN to check if the QTY > 1 do update on odetails -1 and insert into RECORDS and REMOVED tables?

Comment: Did I provide you with sufficient information? I only put the tables that the procedure work with!

Comment: You need to add the insert statements for the data in your tables that corresponds to the expected output in your question.

Comment: I added more data in the tables! so basically  reducing the QTY from the ODETAILS table and add the DELETED_ODETAILS table.

Comment: We need both the before and after states of the data.

Comment: I hope I included everything

Comment: In your records table, you have a column marked `cno`. Should that be `pno`?

Comment: It's the customer number. I added the tables that are associated with the orders

Comment: if it's the customer number, how do you know which parts have been sent back? How can you match the rows in records back to the odetails table without the corresponding pno?

Comment: I check the orders if they are existed in the odetails - pno, ono. if there are records corresponding the odetails, order number will stay in the orders table. However, if the all odetails are moved for a particular order, then I remove the order from the orders table. The procedure works this way by removing from odetails for the correspondent order, however i want to do the same concept but to reduce from QTY. If the QTY in the odetails is equal to 1 then it will be inserted into deleted_odetails and removed from odetails. If it is the only record for ono then the delete will occur in orders

Comment: I don't use the customer number and don't consider it in the procedure

Comment: I know you don't, but it's your records table which determines which rows to amend/remove from the `odetails` table etc, right? If so, where you've got two rows for `ono = 1112` and `cno = 12345` in the `records` table, how do you determine which rows in the `odetails` table are affected, given there's no mention of `pno` in the `records` table?

Comment: sincere apologies, i altered it

Comment: Still doesn't help. Anyway, I've put an answer down below - you'll have to go through it and either update your table structure accordingly or amend my answer yourself. It should be enough to get you started, anyway.

Comment: Cheers Thank you for your time and I do appreciate your help. I will go through the code

Comment: Oh, hang on; are you saying that removed_odetails will be prepopulated before running the code? If so, then I misunderstood, and I'll rework my answer

Comment: yes, it has to be populated .

Comment: Your solution didn't work really well, I managed to be so close from the solution but inserting the deleted order from the first time doesn't go into the DELETED_ODETAILS!!

Comment: `DELETED_ODETAILS`? Is that a new table that you haven't mentioned yet? And what do you mean by my solution "didn't work really well"? When you say you're close to the solution, what are you doing? Running my code, or your own code as per your question? Also, perhaps this would be best continued as comments on my answer?

Comment: Sorry I renamed the REMOVED_ODETAILS. Right, I added a new parameter asking about the QTY. then check against the ones in the ODETAILS.  IF ( VAL2 .QTY >  P_QTY) THEN
        FOR R IN (SELECT DISTINCT ONO, PNO FROM REMOVED_ODETAILS) LOOP
        IF (R.PNO = NULL OR R.PNO = NULL ) THEN                             INSERT
          INTO REMOVED_ODETAILS ELSE UPDATE REMOVED_ODETAILS

Comment: The second insert of the REMOVED_ODETAILS won't work!!

Comment: Seems I misunderstood your question, d'oh. Will amend my answer.

Comment: Can I post the update I made and you will comment where my code doesn't function

Comment: The code I made all functional apart this bit - FOR R IN (SELECT ONO, PNO FROM REMOVED_ODETAILS) LOOP
  --CODE NOT CHECK TO INSERT OR UPDATE ON REMOVED_ODETAILS
    IF (R.ONO != ORD_NUM AND R.PNO != PRO_NUM) THEN

Comment: The reason for that is that you're selecting from the 'removed_odetails' table. If the table is empty to start with, then there is nothing to select, so you won't even enter the loop. Have you tried my latest answer? I think that does everything you need, and will be easier to understand, maintain and debug than your current code. No cursors, no loops, just good ol' straight-forward DML.

Comment: Do you have any idea why my code is not working as it should be!! I am really frustrated as I have spent really good hours trying and trying with it but with no luck

Comment: Uh I understand, So how can I check on empty table and perform  a condition if the row is empty do insert, else update?! Your code is working. However, I just want my code work as I spent many hours and I will be really frustrated with myself!

Comment: I did it without the  for loop but opened new cursor on REMOVED_ODETAILS then put if Valcur3.PNO IS NULL AND Valcur3.ONO IS NULL. I managed to insert or update to the REMOVED_ODETAILS, but the QTY in this table is +1 !!

Comment: You've overthought it, I think. All you needed was a merge statement, instead of the cursor for loop! Seriously, I think you need to take a step back and work out the basics of what you're trying to do - eg. "add a row into records; add a row into removed_odetails if one not already present, otherwise update the qty being removed; update the qty in the odetails table, or delete the row if the qty becomes 0; delete any orders that don't have any details any more.". Simplifies each step, and it's easy to see where you can just use a single DML statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would write the procedure:

```
create or replace procedure one_by_one (p_ord_num in number,
                                        p_pro_num in number,
                                        p_qty in number)
is
begin
  insert into records (id_number, ono, cno, date_send, condition)
  select records_seq.nextval,
         o.ono,
         o.cno,
         trunc(sysdate) date_send, -- should include the time? if so, remove the trunc()
         'SEND BACK' condition
  from   orders o
         cross join (select level lvl
                     from   dual
                     connect by level <= p_qty) d
  where  o.ono = p_ord_num
  and    shipped is not null;

  merge into removed_odetails tgt
  using (select p_ord_num ono,
                p_pro_num pno,
                p_qty qty
         from   dual) src
    on (tgt.ono = src.ono and tgt.pno = src.pno)
  when not matched then
    insert (tgt.ono, tgt.pno, tgt.qty)
    values (src.ono, src.pno, src.qty)
  when matched then
    update
    set tgt.qty = tgt.qty + src.qty;

  merge into odetails tgt
  using (select p_ord_num ono,
                p_pro_num pno,
                p_qty qty
         from   dual) src
    on (tgt.ono = src.ono and tgt.pno = src.pno)
  when matched then
    update set tgt.qty = tgt.qty - case when tgt.qty > src.qty then src.qty end
    delete 
    where tgt.qty is null;

  delete from orders
  where ono = p_ord_num
  and   ono not in (select ono
                    from   odetails
                    where  ono = p_ord_num);
end;
/
```

And here's a test case to demonstrate it working:

```
drop procedure one_by_one;
drop table removed_odetails;
drop table records;
drop table odetails;
drop table orders;
drop sequence records_seq;

create table orders (
  ono      number(5) not null primary key,
  cno      number(5), --references customers,
  eno      number(4), --references employees,
  received date,
  shipped  date);

 create table odetails (
  ono      number(5) not null references orders,
  pno      number(5) not null, --references parts,
  qty      integer check(qty > 0),
  primary key (ono,pno));

create table records (
       id_number  number(5) not null primary key,
       ono        number(5) not null,
       cno        number(5) not null,
       date_send  date,
       condition  varchar2(30));

create sequence records_seq
 start with 10001
  maxvalue 999999999999999999999999999
  minvalue 1
  nocycle
  cache 20
  noorder;

create table removed_odetails ( 
      ono      number(5) not null,
      pno      number(5) not null,
      qty      integer check(qty > 0),
      primary key (ono,pno));

insert into orders (ono, cno, eno, received, shipped)
select 1112 ono, 7000 cno, 1004 eno, to_date('02/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') received, to_date('20/12/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') shipped from dual union all
select 1113 ono, 12345 cno, 2002 eno, to_date('10/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') received, to_date('15/12/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') shipped from dual union all
select 1114 ono, 12345 cno, 2002 eno, to_date('09/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') received, to_date('14/12/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') shipped from dual;

insert into odetails (ono, pno, qty)
select 1112 ono, 12345 pno, 3 qty from dual union all
select 1112 ono, 98766 pno, 3 qty from dual union all
select 1113 ono, 12345 pno, 2 qty from dual union all
select 1114 ono, 12345 pno, 1 qty from dual;

commit;

-- now run the procedure for all rows in removed_odetails:

begin
  for rec in (select 1112 ono, 12345 pno, 2 qty from dual union all
              select 1112 ono, 98766 pno, 1 qty from dual union all
              select 1113 ono, 12345 pno, 1 qty from dual union all
              select 1114 ono, 12345 pno, 1 qty from dual)
  loop
    one_by_one(p_ord_num => rec.ono,
               p_pro_num => rec.pno,
               p_qty => rec.qty);
  end loop;
  commit;
end;
/

select * from orders;

       ONO        CNO        ENO RECEIVED   SHIPPED   
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      1112       7000       1004 02/01/2016 20/12/2015
      1113      12345       2002 10/01/2016 15/12/2015

select * from odetails;

       ONO        PNO        QTY
---------- ---------- ----------
      1112      12345          1
      1112      98766          2
      1113      12345          1

select * from removed_odetails;

       ONO        PNO        QTY
---------- ---------- ----------
      1112      98766          1
      1112      12345          2
      1114      12345          1
      1113      12345          1

select * from records;

 ID_NUMBER        ONO        CNO DATE_SEND  CONDITION                     
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------------
     10001       1112       7000 14/01/2016 SEND BACK                     
     10002       1112       7000 14/01/2016 SEND BACK                     
     10003       1112       7000 14/01/2016 SEND BACK                     
     10004       1113      12345 14/01/2016 SEND BACK                     
     10005       1114      12345 14/01/2016 SEND BACK                     

begin
  for rec in (select 1112 ono, 98766 pno, 1 qty from dual)
  loop
    one_by_one(p_ord_num => rec.ono,
               p_pro_num => rec.pno,
               p_qty => rec.qty);
  end loop;
  commit;
end;
/

select * from orders;

       ONO        CNO        ENO RECEIVED   SHIPPED   
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      1112       7000       1004 02/01/2016 20/12/2015
      1113      12345       2002 10/01/2016 15/12/2015

select * from odetails;

       ONO        PNO        QTY
---------- ---------- ----------
      1112      12345          1
      1112      98766          1
      1113      12345          1

select * from removed_odetails;

       ONO        PNO        QTY
---------- ---------- ----------
      1112      98766          2
      1112      12345          2
      1114      12345          1
      1113      12345          1

select * from records;

 ID_NUMBER        ONO        CNO DATE_SEND  CONDITION                     
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------------
     10001       1112       7000 14/01/2016 SEND BACK                     
     10002       1112       7000 14/01/2016 SEND BACK                     
     10003       1112       7000 14/01/2016 SEND BACK                     
     10004       1113      12345 14/01/2016 SEND BACK                     
     10005       1114      12345 14/01/2016 SEND BACK                     
     10006       1112       7000 14/01/2016 SEND BACK
```

Btw, you see the above test case? That's the type of information you should be providing up front, to avoid wasting the time of those who are volunteering to help you ... for free. Please take that on board when you post future questions!

Comment: I've updated my answer; hopefully this time my procedure does what you're after!

Comment: I've updated my answer again to make sure it works in the case where an order/part is sent back after one has already been sent back.

Answer (score 0):

And here is a working (well, it seems to add only one row per ono/pno combination per call into the records table, rather than the number of rows corresponding to the quantity being deleted) version of your code:

```
create or replace procedure one_by_one( ord_num in number, pro_num in number, quantity number)
as
  cursor cur1
  is
  select * from orders 
  where ono = ord_num;

  cursor cur2
  is
  select * from odetails
  where pno = pro_num
  and   ono = ord_num;

  val1 cur1%rowtype;
  val2 cur2%rowtype;

begin

  open cur1;
  open cur2;

  loop
    fetch cur1 into val1;
    fetch cur2 into val2;

    exit when cur1%notfound;
    exit when cur1%notfound;

    if val1.shipped is not null then
--      if pro_num = val2.pno and ord_num = val2.ono then -- totally unnecessary, since you already did that check as part of the cursor!
      if (val2.qty > quantity) then
        merge into removed_odetails tgt
        using (select ord_num ono,
                      pro_num pno,
                      quantity qty
               from   dual) src
          on (tgt.ono = src.ono and tgt.pno = src.pno)
        when not matched then
          insert (tgt.ono, tgt.pno, tgt.qty)
          values (src.ono, src.pno, src.qty)
        when matched then
          update
          set tgt.qty = tgt.qty + src.qty;

        update odetails
        set    qty = qty - quantity
        where  ono = ord_num
        and    pno = pro_num;

        insert into records(id_number, ono,cno,date_send,condition)
        values(records_seq.nextval, val1.ono,val1.cno,sysdate,'SEND BACK');

      elsif (val2.qty = quantity ) then 
        insert into records(id_number, ono,cno,date_send,condition)
        values (records_seq.nextval, val1.ono,val1.cno,sysdate,'SEND BACK');

        insert into removed_odetails( ono, pno, qty) 
               values(val2.ono,val2.pno, val2.qty);

        delete from odetails where ono = ord_num and pno = pro_num;
      end if;  

      dbms_output.put_line('Item will be send back ');

      delete from orders 
      where ono = ord_num
      and   not exists (select null from odetails where ono = ord_num);

    elsif val1.shipped is null then
      dbms_output.put_line('DO NOTHING ');
    end if;
  end loop;

  close cur1;
  close cur2;
end one_by_one;
/
```

You were attempting to reinvent the `MERGE` statement, when you were attempting to check if a row already existed or not in the removed_odetails table, so all I've done is remove the cursor-for-loop and have the merge statement instead (and changed the update of the removed_odetails table into updating the odetails table).

I wouldn't recommend this particular solution though; it's much less straightforward than the other solution I provided. You will curse yourself if you need to maintain this code at any time in the future! (We've all been there...)

Comment: Thank you very much for your patient and your help! Really appreciate it. However, I hope you will be patient with me one more time. Question, Do you think the cursor can do the MERGE statement ! Then within the cursor can check if the REMOVED_ODETAILS empty do insert otherwise update? Just wondering !

Comment: Probably, but when you're working with code, it really pays to keep it simple. The simpler the code is, the easier it is to maintain, debug and understand, plus in all likelihood, it'll perform much better than it's more complex counterpart (although obviously there are always exceptions!). I really can't stress that enough!

Comment: I understand that, probably lack of experience from my side as this is the first time I worked in PL/SQL

Comment: {nods} I think you're thinking extremely procedurally (aka row-by-row). When it comes to the database, it's very powerful at doing set operations - eg. don't go "here's a cursor, get a row, insert the row, get the next row, insert that row, etc..." as you can just do "insert into tablex select ..." instead. Faster, better, easier to read, less code etc etc. If you're used to thinking procedurally, it can be difficult to make the shift to thinking set-based! Maybe [this blog post](http://www.orchestrapit.co.uk/?p=171) will be of some use?

Comment: I totally I agree with you and I like DML as fast, accurate and code effecient. However, I am trying my best to be good at both, well still newbie but learning :)

Comment: It's very obvious that you are trying - and that is a very good sign *{:-D When I first started learning to code PL/SQL it took me a while to "get" how to think set-based, rather than procedurally! What helped me a lot was to read [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/) and see the answers being put up there. Also trying to answer other people's questions on forums or set up test cases to follow other people's answers was another way I gained experience and knowledge. Good luck with your learning *{:-)

Comment: It's very kind of you to help and support others and hope I could be skilled and professional just like you. Thank you very much for your time and I really appreciate it

Comment: Sorry again, but I have a question. How to cover   merge into removed_odetails tgt to a FOR cursor loop ?

Comment: Typically, you wouldn't do that. What most people would do instead is something that's known as an upsert: try inserting the row then if you get a unique constraint violation, try an update instead, or vice-versa.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have tried update but when I try to remove an order for the first time it won't do it! I think the condition I put is not working as appropriate. This one incerments the insert into the removed_odetails +1    IF VAR_CUR1.SHIPPED IS NOT NULL THEN
     
       IF ( VAR_CUR2.QTY > P_QTY ) THEN
        
        IF  CUR_QTY%NOTFOUND THEN
             
        INSERT
          INTO removed_odetails
         INSERT
          INTO record
           
             UPDATE ODETAILS SET QTY = QTY - P_QTY WHERE ONO = P_ONO AND PNO = PNUM;

Comment: I am really close to do it. However, I still get the answer +2 for the insert into REMOVED_ODETAILS +1 :/ I am trying to check if this QTY is not exist in the REMOVED_ODETAILS based on the PNO and ONO in this table, then do the Insert into REMOVED_ODETAILS, Insert into RECORDS and then -1 the QTY in ODETAILS . The only problem left is the Insert into REMOVED_ODETAILS !!